# non-ordinary constraint in an ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody recommend a numerical scheme to solve this regular ODE $$\dot x =f(x,y)$$$$\dot y=g(x,y)$$ with the initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ is given along with the ratio constraint $k$ of the time averages $\left \langle x \right \rangle=k\left \langle y \right \rangle$ where the time average is defined as $\left \langle a \right \rangle=lim_{T\to\infty} \frac {1}{T}\int_0^T {a(t)dt}$

Comment: It's not always that constraint uniquely determines the evolution. If the system has an attractive fixpoint $(x_*,y_*)$ then $\left<x\right> = x_*$ and $\left<y\right> = y_*$ regardless of the value of $y(0)$. As for solving it: the simplest brute force way is to pick different values for $y(0) = y_0$, integrate long enough so that the averages have stabilized (if they do) and then see if it matches. Once you have found $y(0)$ such that $\frac{<y>}{<x>} = k$ you are done. One can improve this method by adjusting $y(0)$ more smartly.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I am asking for your help in picking it "more smartly".

Comment: Once you have two values $y_1,y_2$ of $y(0)$ such that $\left(\frac{<x>}{<y>}\right)_{1} > k$ and $\left(\frac{<x>}{<y>}\right)_{2} < k$ then you can use [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find new values to try. This should converge quite quickly.

Comment: i will try it, thank you.

Comment: The general class of algorithms that are used to solve these types of problems are often called *shoot-and-match* algorithms. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_multiple_shooting_method).